# ExtJS refreshing a view from the controller

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have the following controller in ExtJs:

```
Ext.define('FileBrowser.controller.BrowserController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views: ['browser.tree_dir', 'browser.grid_file'],
    stores: ['store_dir', 'store_file'],

    init: function () {
        this.control({
            'window > tree_dir': {
                itemclick: {
                    fn: function (view, record, item, index, event) {
                        if (record.isLeaf() == false) {
                            Ext.getStore('store_file').load({
                                params: {
                                    dir: record.data.id
                                }
                            });
                            var parentOfCurrentFiles = record.data.id
                            nodeId = record.data.id;
                            htmlId = item.id;
                            var grid_view = this.getView('browser.grid_file');
                            var grid_view_v = grid_view.getView();
                            grid_view_v.refresh();
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
        });
    },
    onPanelRendered: function () {
        console.log('The panel was rendered');
    }
});
```

If you notice under 'itemclick' I am trying to refresh one of my views, my approach is not working. Can anyone explain to me how I can refresh the view? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `var grid_view= this.getView('browser.grid_file');` with `var grid_view= this.getView('browser.grid_file').create();` to get a real instance (as I already told you, `getView() only return the view config, not a instance!`) or if you have already created that grid and only one instance exist use the xtype along with a component query to receive it `var grid_view=Ext.ComponentQuery('grid_file')[0]`

Now to the refresh()

Basically you never need to call this method cause your grid is bound to a store and any change made on this store is directly reflected to your grid.

I would also recommend you to store view instances when creating them instead of using queries or directly use the **[ref](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-refs)** property and let ExtJS do the work for you. The last one will the best solution you I guess... Take a look at ref's within the API examples and give it a try.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't the issue but the fact that you said that I don't need that line put me on the right path. Turns out the issue was in my store file, under `Model:`  I entered only the model file name rather than the entire name. Once I entered the full name everything worked with just the store load.

Comment: @ArtF As long as it worked out for you :) Thanks for accepting

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is, load the store and have the data reflect once you refresh the grid_view...?
In that case, you haven't done a `setStore()` to the grid, or if you have done that elsewhere, you are't doing a `setData()` to the store. Also you should call the refresh on the grid.

Comment: What are you talking about? Your answer make no sense at all